# which data range picker i can use?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone help me to find out date range picker.

Data picker with min and max days selection,holidays disable to select.

I used `bootstrap data range picker` but i did not get max number of days limit in that.

```
var dateToday = new Date();

$(function() {
    $('input[name="absence[from_date]"]').daterangepicker({
         minDate: dateToday,
         maxDay: '+30d',
         locale: {
             format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
         }
     });
 });
```

i did this code but this will give only 30 days from current date.

Comment: It is giving you 30 days from now because you have set `maxDay: '+30d'`, you can pass `maxDay: '+3m'` it will show the next 3 month dates from now.

Comment: @AmitSharma that right but i don't ant that. I want only 30 days disable from my selected date.

Comment: ok can you please explain in detail about your problem and requirement.

Comment: i want a data range picker,which can have below functions.
(1)start from today's date,
(2)30 day max user can select.
(3)holidays like Sundays and all are disables for selection.